# Why is the generic specified after the access level keyword

Tags: java, generics, syntax, option-type

I was looking at the implementation of `Optional.map`, which is this:

```
public<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
        if (!isPresent())
            return empty();
        else {
            return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value));
        }
    }
```

What is `public<U>`? Why is the generic specified after the access level modifier?

Why is the method not declared like this?

```
public Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
```

Comment: What is package of class `Optional`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic specification of **a method**. The `U` doesn't come from the class, but the same method can take any kind of mapper `Function`, and will return the appropriate `Optional<U>` for it.